# Word frequency counter on specific words using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to count number of predetermined words (wordlist) in a text. This is what I have done so far:

```
function frequencies(text, wordlist){
  var words = text.split(/\s/);
  var freqMap = {};
  words.forEach(function(w){
    if (!freqMap[w] && wordlist){
      freqMap[w] = 0;
    }
    freqMap[w] += 1;
  });
  return freqMap;

}
```

At the moment it counts all the words in given text, how do I make it count only words given in wordlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check word is in given list using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method( or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method).

```
function frequencies(text, wordlist) {
  var words = text.split(/\s/);
  var freqMap = {};
  words.forEach(function(w) {
    if (wordlist && wordlist.indexOf(w) > -1) { // or wordlist.includes(w)
      if (!freqMap[w]) {
        freqMap[w] = 0;
      }
      freqMap[w] += 1;
    }
  });
  return freqMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example accounts for some basic punctuation in the text. It will remove said punctuation, split on spaces, then uses reduce to build the object you're wanting.

```js
let wordlist = ['hello', 'bob', 'you', 'later'];
let text = 'hello bob, how are you doing? i hope you are doing well. see you later.';

function frequencies(text, wordlist) {
  return text.replace(/(\.|\?|,)/g, '').split(' ').reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (wordlist.includes(curr)) {
      if (prev[curr])
        prev[curr]++;
      else
        prev[curr] = 1;
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

console.log(frequencies(text, wordlist))
```